# is it possible to auto refresh tree view in openerp?

Tags: javascript, python, odoo

is it possible to auto refresh tree view ,I am using OpenERP 7.0. I tried "1" in action of the tree view, but did not work for me.I need it on web client.

Answer (score -1):

try with your own javascript. add to **openerp**.py your javascript file path

ex : -

```
'data': [
         ...  
         'static/src/js/your_file_name.js'],
```

then identify the trigger point which u want to execute your function.then write code for that.
here is my way,
in eclipse press select **tree** tag then **ctrl+alt+G** and search in whole workplace & find same scenario.then apply it to your module.its like a overriding
:-)

Comment: I did not get your answer can you please elaborate more?